# swift web request not submitting (using alamofire)

Tags: xcode, swift, httpwebrequest, alamofire

I'm speculating that my request is incomplete...I can't figure out what piece I'm missing.  When I run this, nothing submits, it just hangs forever...please help!

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class getToken: UIViewController {


let headers = [
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "application/json"]

func fetchToken(contentID: String, completion: ([String]) -> Void) {
Alamofire.request(
    .GET,
    "https://secure3.saashr.com:443/ta/rest/v1/login?company=slszdr&username=abc&password=123",
    headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let name = json["name"].stringValue
            print(name)
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
}}}
```

and this is the call from my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getToken()
}}
```

Comment: you haven't called fetchToken method, you only declared it

Comment: @Set can you give some more details?  I don't see how I haven't called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View controller class, I see this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
getToken()
}
```

This seems wrong. Because you are creating an instance of getToken "class",
And you never really called you method fetchtoken()
 I think you must change this to something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let instanceOfGetTokenClass = getToken()
    instanceOfGetTokenClass.fetchToken(// send parameters here)
}
```

Maybe you got confused with class name "getToken" and method name "fetchToken" :)